# Developing a plugin where users can edit entries saved in database

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu

it's the first time I'm writing a plugin. So far, it creates a table in database on activation, users can add entries to database and they can check saved entries.

I've added Edit and Delete links where I pass the id, but I don't want to edit entries on a different page. How to do it so it's on the same "environment"? 
Make it something like Users in WordPress, that kind of functionality?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: It makes database table on activation and deletes it on delete, it has menu where you can see all the records created so far and a submenu item where you can add a new record that gets saved to database. Now I don't know how to edit records using the plugin development logic.

Comment: Okay! When you are listing result make link on items. e.g. `site/edit-record?id=x` edit-record will be your new page and on this page you will get record ID. Populate it then update it on save. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Yes, I did something similar with edit.php?id=x.
The thing is, my edit.php page is independent, it's just the edit form, it doesn't look like a part of dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it, but probably there is a much cleaner WP way of doing these things.

So, I have a menu page that I've added using add_menu_page. On it, I display all the records. The url is:

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=plugin-settings (or whatever you call it)
```

I use:

```
<a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url');?>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=utm-user-plugin-settings&id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>">Edit</a>
```

So basically, I ended up using the same page for my EDIT action by checking if $_GET["id"] is set or not.

Again, there is probably a better way to do this, I just don't know it yet, so this will do for now.

Comment: I am also stucked in same problem & this solution is not working for me. I am getting this error. "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Comment: Where exactly do you get this message? When you click edit or...?